# Is there a STANDARD way of coding CSS for all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have the following issue:

I am making this website... I'm using html and CSS. I've been trying to maintain CSS as standard as possible and checking as I go with the three main browsers: chrome, firefox, and ie. In MY pc it seems to be working fine (with the exception of minor details). However, when other people open it in other screen dimensions , things fall out of place. Does anyone know why this might be happening? take a look at what i'm talking about this is the homepage:

www.britobmarketing.com/ledtogo/index.html

I bet it will be a little unaligned in some of your computers, but in mine it looks perfect. It's stressful!!!

Also, as I was saying, I'm trying to keep the CSS standard so that every browser can view it the same. But browsers like Firefox and ie do not recognize the "round edges" effect on the three buttons I have besides the video. It does work on the rest though, which is what confuses me! Anyone has any idea why this might be happening?

Thank you very much for your time and help!!

Comment: Sadly, that's just the way things are. Different browsers render pages differently.

Comment: by the way, the hover effect on those three buttons doesn't work on ie and firefox. It does expand the box, but not with the nice fading i programmed it to do. That's one more thing that puzzles me, since i DID use the recommended code to make it work in other browsers as well...

Comment: It's also the way it was meant to be. It's not typography, although CSS does come pretty close at times.

Comment: You need to learn the fundamentals of HTML layout so that you can control the look of your page in different width windows.  This looks like purely a width issue.  Just take your own browser window and resize it to see what I mean.  You have to decide if you want a fixed with design or a flexible width design and, if fixed, set the width of a container.  If flexible, then use containers and alignment to control how things align themselves.

Comment: I used to use a table to align the overall page and make the footer, header, and contents aligned. However, i read somewhere that using tables to align the overall layout is not good practice. What do you guys recommend? And yes, @jfriend00, i do know the fundamentals of HTML and aligning, but I was trying to align it using CSS instead... I was told it was more professional. Is it?

Comment: HTML and CSS work together.  You apply CSS rules to HTML objects.  It is more modern (and generally more flexible) to use CSS rules to control formatting of your HTML objects.  Your header, indexcontainter and footer are all separate top level objects and are all different widths.  If you put them all in one containing div and set the width of that div, then you page will be a fixed width to which you can align all the elements to.  Or, you can let that container width be flexible and center items in it.  In either case, you need CSS and probably containing div to align things to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *not* an issue of browser rendering engines doing things different.

You aren't taking into account a variable width of the viewport. Your header and footer are centered, and your content is fixed left.  So as the viewport gets wider, the header footer stay and the center and slides left.

So for your content, here's the problem:

```
#indexcontainter {
  width: 980px;
  height: 390px;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 170px;
}
```

In your header, `margin: auto` is what does the centering, making the left and right margin automatically equal each other.  But for the content, you hard code a left margin at `170px`.

Change that to use automargins and it starts to work great:

```
#indexcontainter {
  width: 980px;
  height: 390px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: GREAT!! that was exactly what i needed i think.. And yes, maybe I'm missing some of the basic CSS skills since i just learned it looking at examples and from experience using it... haven't gone much into tutorials... anyways, THANK YOU!! any Idea about the round edges and hover effect?

Comment: @Brito Getting cross browser support for border radius is a whole other question. One that's likely been answered a lot already. Search this site.